# Add some numbers in front of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in SQL server and I want to add 7 for the words which begin by a and add 8 for the words which begin by t.

Here is my column:

```
    add-on
    above
    tv
    their
    french
```

And I want this:

```
    7add-on
    7above
    8tv
    8their
    french
```

I am looking for a query which could do that.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us what you have already tried and how your attempts failed.

Comment: You want rename column name ?

Comment: Use a case expression, left() and concat().

Comment: Are you trying to store this back to the string data itself?  As another column alongside the string data?  Dynamically in the results of a query containing the string data?  Something else?  Modifying the data itself doesn't seem wise...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left()` & do the concatenation :

```
select t.*,
       (case left(col, 1) 
             when 'a' then concat(7, col) 
             when 't' then concat(8, col) 
             else col 
        end)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a case expression with substring to get the results you require.

```
select concat(
       (case when substring(col,1,1)='a' then '7' 
             when substring(col,1,1)='t' then '8'
         end
        )
       ,col
       ) as modified_col
  from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 update queries. Try like:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn='7'+myColumn WHERE myColumn LIKE 'a%';
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn='8'+myColumn WHERE myColumn LIKE 't%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement to check the first char, returned by [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, and calculate a prefix to add to your data:

```
select
    case substring(column, 1, 1)
    when 'a' then '7'
    when 't' then '8' else '' end + column as NewColumn
from table
```

Comment: case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server 2008 :

```
 select
    case when substring(column,1,1)='a'  then ( '7 ' + column) 
    case when substring(column,1,1)='t' then  ( '8 ' + column) 
    else column end as column from table
```

In sql server 2012 or above  :

```
  select
    case when substring(column,1,1)='a'  then concat( '7 ',column) 
    case when substring(column,1,1)='t' then  concat( '8 ',column) 
    else column end as column from table
```

Comment: The scripts you provide both of them same. Also substr is not sql-server function. I believe you meant SUBSTRING() .

Comment: yes I meant SUBSTRING(). Since OP doesn't mention which version he is using I written in both version